# voltage regulator connected between positive and negative voltages

Tags: voltage-regulator, ground, negative

I'm kind of new to the world of electronics, so bear with me.
I need to regulate +24 volts down to about +21 volts (for supplying a really pretentious heating resistor). I already have the circuit for the v-reg using +24v. The problem I'm having is that I don't have +24 volts, but I do have +12 and -12 volts. Could I connect the input of the v-reg to +12v and use the -12v as the circuit's GND?
The voltages come from a PC PSU.

This is basically what I need:

[image: This is basically what I need]

EDIT: I calculated the output as +9V. Combined with -12V the load should get 21V, right?
But now I'm not sure about what I use for the ULN2003's ground? Should I use the actual GND or should I leave it to -12V.
Thanks.
[image: Could this work?]

Comment: Depends on what the voltages are referenced to. Update your question to include a schematic or wiring diagram that shows where your voltages are coming from and how you want to connect them together.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a ±12 V supply as a 24 V supply, because it is.  Taken in isolation that is fine.

You can run into trouble when you connect your circuit to something else that uses a different ground, and those grounds are not floating with respect to each other.  Your circuit views the -12 V supply as ground, which is fine for it.  However, if you try to connect signals to it that use the same power supply 0 V line as their reference, your circuit will view all those signals as being 12 V higher than the driving circuit.  That probably isn't good.

If, in contrast, you connect your circuit to another one that is powered from a separate wall wart, then you can choose whatever point on each circuit you consider the 0 V reference and connect them together.  This works because the power supplies for the two circuits are *isolated* from each other.  That means the voltages of each can float arbitrarily relative to the other.  By connecting the two grounds, you define a common reference between the two otherwise floating circuits, and then after that they are not floating with respect to each other anymore.

Comment: So, basically, the first one works (the one with just +/-12V), while the second one "sees" only 12V and 0V with the v-reg output somewhere in between, right?